# Excel - Need a master list of items populated as they're entered randomly in a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table, 12 columns x 26 rows, where names will be entered in cells at random.  I'd like to generate a list of these names in the order that they're entered in the table.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not very clear.`in the order that they're entered in the table` ? So `A1` would be first....does `A2` come after that or does `B1` come next ?! Or do you want something like NickSlash has specified i.e. returned in the cronological order that they were entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't really specify where you wanted the list etc so I've taken some liberties with it.

The code will monitor `Range(A1:L26)` and do the following

> If any text is added it will add the item to the list (which is column N and M).
>   If the value inside that cell is later modified it will update the initial list item.
>   If the value is cleared the list item will be removed shifting the remaining list items up one.

Copy the following code into a worksheet module (eg: Sheet1 if you want it active on sheet 1)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Row As Integer
Dim List As Range
Set List = Range("N1")
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:L26")) Is Nothing Then
    Row = 0
    Do
        If List.Offset(RowOFfset:=Row).Value = "" Then
            ' End of list or empty list, add item to list
            List.Offset(RowOFfset:=Row).Value = Target.Address
            List.Offset(RowOFfset:=Row, ColumnOffset:=1).Value = Target.Value
            Exit Do
        Else
            If List.Offset(RowOFfset:=Row).Value = Target.Address Then
                ' Target has been added already
                If Target.Value = "" Then
                    ' Target has been cleared, remove the item from the list and shift list up
                    Range(List.Offset(RowOFfset:=Row), List.Offset(RowOFfset:=Row, ColumnOffset:=1)).Delete xlShiftUp
                Else
                    ' Target has changed, update the list item (in place)
                    List.Offset(RowOFfset:=Row, ColumnOffset:=1).Value = Target.Value
                End If
                Exit Do
            Else
                Row = Row + 1
            End If
        End If
    Loop
Else
    ' Invalid Target
End If
End Sub
```

**Update**

I've change the code to hopefully do what you wanted. I was a little confused by "every other 2 columns", so I hope you meant columns B, E, H, K....

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Row As Integer
Dim List As Range
Dim Column As Integer

    Set List = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Column = Target.Column
    ' This is used to determine if the column is one we are looking for
    ' eg: 2-3 = -1, 5-3-3 = -1, 8-3-3-3 = -1 etc
    Do
        Column = Column - 3
        If Column <= 0 Then Exit Do
    Loop

    If Column = -1 Then
        If Target.Row > 2 And Target.Row < 27 Then
            ' Target Match
            Row = 0
            Do
                If List.Offset(RowOffset:=Row).Value = "" Then
                    ' End of list or empty list, add item to list
                    List.Offset(RowOffset:=Row).Value = Target.Address
                    List.Offset(RowOffset:=Row, ColumnOffset:=1).Value = Target.Value
                    List.Offset(RowOffset:=Row, ColumnOffset:=2).Value = Cells(2, Target.Column).Value
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    If List.Offset(RowOffset:=Row).Value = Target.Address Then
                        ' Target has been added already
                        If Target.Value = "" Then
                            ' Target has been cleared, remove the item from the list and shift list up
                            Range(List.Offset(RowOffset:=Row), List.Offset(RowOffset:=Row, ColumnOffset:=2)).Delete xlShiftUp
                        Else
                            ' Target has changed, update the list item (in place)
                            List.Offset(RowOffset:=Row, ColumnOffset:=1).Value = Target.Value
                        End If
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        Row = Row + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Loop
        Else
            ' Target Column, Non-Target Row
        End If
    Else
        ' Non-Target Column
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @NickSlash.  Apologies for not specifying.  This works great. I'm just getting started with this type of scripting so I'd be interested to know if there are any books, site or courses you'd recommend for a beginner like me? I was wondering how I could do 2 additional things:

1. I'd like to adjust the range so that I can include every other 2 columns starting at B3:B26 through AO3:AO26.
2. In addition to bringing in the address the value came from, also bring in the column name (which would always be set in the 2nd row for each corresponding column.

Comment: The language itself is fairly easy to get due to the commands being in English, the harder part is figuring out how to do what you want. Just give it a go, you can always ask more questions (make sure to include examples of how you've tried to solve the problem yourself though!)